# refresh page with reset button

Tags: jquery, html

I want to reset my page with a button.

This is my code:

```
$(".reset").click(function () {
    document.location.reload(true);
});
```

```
<button id="reset">RESET</button>
```

Anyone an idea what I have to change?

Answer (score 4):

Hi You have defined id as reset for the button and in jquery code called as class so it should be:

```
$("#reset").click(function(){
  document.location.reload(true);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: My page doesn't refresh. Is there another way?

Comment: It should refresh your page, is it possible to take a look at your html page

Comment: @gladius - A few errors .. You still did not change `id` to `class` or vice versa.. also not provided jQuery library in the fiddle. Here is an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kj76gxxr/3/). I recommend that you look at [jQuery basics](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/)..

Comment: Normally i use Aptana Studios, there i have Jquery library and the other things works. Tnx

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `true` from your function reload

```
location.reload()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<button type="reset">RESET</button>
```

or

```
<button type="reset" onclick="document.location.reload()">RESET</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#reset").click(function(){ 
  location.reload();
  });
});
</script>
```

You can try this

Comment: It doesn't work. And I don't know why. Wich jquery do you use?

Comment: above code is working fine I tried as you can see here [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DrR7s/237/)

Comment: I am using <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: it works in a new html page but not in the page I use

Answer (score 0):

I am using following page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e){


 $("#reset").click(function(){
      document.location.reload(true);
});


});



</script>
</head>

<body>
<button id="reset">RESET</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: sorry. I am doing this like you say and it doens't want to work in the htmlpage I am working in. In a new page it works.

Comment: I am not sure how you are trying to do this, it will be great if you can show me the code where you are using this.

Comment: I have checked your code and it's having some error, that's why reset button is not loading and refreshing